# I am trying to import BIND settings from OS X Server 5.0.3 into BIND 9.14.4 on Mojave Server

Tags: macos, mojave, server.app

I am trying to import all my settings from the DNS tab of Mac OS X Server 5.0.3 on Yosemite into a third party BIND install on Mojave since it doesn't exist in the App anymore :( I see the 'named' folder in the old server library and so I can see all the settings but does anyone know a way to get BIND 9.14.4 to read these files on the new server? Where would I put them?

I read an article as to where to put the named.conf file but none of the others. It seems that once they are in the correct location in regards to the conf file they should all be accessible.

Comment: it seems named.conf lives in the /usr/local/etc/ folder